# Is there a way to throw a customize instead of the default error message?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE Departments 
(
    did INTEGER,
    dname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(did)
);

CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    eid SERIAL,
    ename VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
    did INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(eid),
    FOREIGN KEY(did) REFERENCES Departments (did),
);
```

We can only delete a department if there is no employee currently assigned to that department. I want to throw a custom error to inform the user that there are still employees assigned to that department using a trigger.

However, it still throws the standard SQL error

> [23503] ERROR: update or delete on table "departments" violates foreign key constraint "employees_did_fkey" on table "employees" Detail: Key (did)=(1) is still referenced from table "employees"

instead of the customized error that I want to throw.

How can I do that? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change PostgreSQL error messages is to modify the source code.

You could use a PL/pgSQL function to modify the table, catch the error and `RAISE` your own exception.